# Python import fails in windows, but not linux

Tags: python, linux, windows, python-2.7, import

When I import a module, it works on linux, but fails in windows, with the error:

```
<Directory>\src>main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<Directory>\src\main.py", line 12, in <module>
    from parser.parser import Parser
ImportError: No module named parser
```

On windows it seems that it cannot find the file `parser.py` (created by me). I don't understand why because it found all the other modules.

```
[folder:
   - main.py
   - parser/__init__.py
   - parser/parser.py]
```

Comment: are the directory sturctures, and python versions exactly the same?

Comment: yes it's the same program and the same version of python

Comment: is the space in `__ init__.py` a type-o?

Comment: there is no space... i had to do it to write it here

Comment: @Frenkyk don't think you did, i jsut removed it (the space)

Comment: Is the capitalisation of the folders exactly as shown there too?

Comment: It should fail on both Linux and Windows. Rename the top-level package e.g., `frenkyk_parser/parser.py`

Comment: same error if i rename

Comment: @Frenkyk: have you changed the import to correspond to the new name?

Comment: Yes ...anyway in that case it wouldn't have run on linux too, but there it work.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is with the package name    `parser`    . By importing `from parser` you import the `parser` module from the standard library that has no `parser.parser` submodule. See [parser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/parser.html).

Comment: Did you rename the directory parser to something else? Because it is the one conflicting.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same problem, and got it solved.

Here's how.

Check your sys.path (import it first) to see whether your coding-file's directory is included in it. If not, append it.

That's my code:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path[0]=os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

Tell me if it doesn't work.

BTW, I'm Chinese so ignore any grammatical errors. I think you understand what I mean.