# python - import error from a sibling folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import, python-packaging

I'm working on a **python 3.8.5** project which has this folder structure:

```
project/
    ├── __init__.py
    |── foo.py
    |── bar.py
    ├── utils/
    │   ├── __init__py
    │   └── configurator.py
    └── server/
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── models.py
```

In `server/models.py` I need to use a class *Configurator* declared inside `utils/configurator.py`:

```
# server/models.py
from utils.configurator import Configurator

# some code here ...
```

Unfortunately I get this error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'`. I dont't understand how it cannot find the *utils* module since I've properly set the ***init**.py* file inside that folder.

I've also tried with relative import:

```
# server/models.py
from ..utils.configurator import Configurator
    
# some code here ...
```

this time getting the following error: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Finally, I've attempted with an absolute import, with no results again:

```
# server/models.py
from projects.utils.configurator import Configurator
    
# some code here ...
```

The error this time is: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'projects'`

Based on [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34461987/python3-importerror-no-module-named-xxxx) it seems correct to me, I can't understand what I'm messing with.

My code editor is *Visual Studio Code* and when I type *from utils.* ... it gives the right suggestion, although I don't think this piece of information could be of any utility.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you manage to find a work around it?

Comment: [look at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26384041/python-import-fails-in-windows-but-not-linux) add this lines at the beginning of each python file    ```                                                                
        import os, sys
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
        sys.path[0]=os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))                                                      ```